# URLCompression + Response Filter Conflict

Tags: asp.net-2.0, iis-7.5

I have IIS 7.5 with URL compression enabled for dynamic content. I wanted to add a response filter to remove modify the rendered html and for some reason I kept getting garbage data while filtering.

The code for the response filter's write method is below:

```
    Encoding encoding = HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding;
    string html = encoding.GetString(buffer);

    html = regFindFollow.Replace(html, new MatchEvaluator(AddFollowNoFollowAttribute));

    byte[] outdata = encoding.GetBytes(html);
```

This starts to work when I remove URL compression from web config. Am I missing something here? Is there an order for response filters that can be specified?

Config I am using is

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the config with

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
```

Fixed this. I suppose during the execution module received compressed html and couldn't parse it.